# Alternate method of proving purely imaginary roots of a cubic polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Doing some practice exam questions, and came across this problem:

*The polynomial $P(x)=x^3 + qx^2 + rx + s$ has real coefficients. It has three distinct zeros, $\alpha$, $-\alpha$ and $\beta$.*

***i)*** Prove that $qr = s$

***ii)*** The polynomial does not have three real zeros. Show that two of the zeros are purely imaginary. (A number is purely imaginary if it is of the form $iy$, with $y$ real and $y \neq 0$.)

I did ***i)*** no problem, and assumed that it would connect to ***ii)***. However, my first thought upon seeing it was a logical solution, and not using ***i)***. My reasoning is thus:

*If $q$, $r$ and $s$ are real, and the polynomial does not have three real zeros (given in **ii)**) then $P(x)$ must have exactly 2 complex roots (a complex number and its conjugate) and 1 real root.*

*Since the roots are $\alpha$, $-\alpha$ and $\beta$, and the negative of a complex number is still a complex number, then $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ must be the complex roots (and the conjugate of one another), and $\beta$ must be the real root.*

*Let $\alpha = x + iy$. Since $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ are the conjugate of one another, $\overline{x + iy} = -(x + iy).$*
$\therefore x-iy = -x-iy$

*This is only true when $x = 0$.*
$\therefore \alpha = 0 + iy = iy$
$\therefore -\alpha = -iy$

Am I correct in my reasoning, and is this sufficient proof?

Comment: Yes.  That's correct.